# MKMultiPolylineRenderer with attributes?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolyline, mkmultipolylinerenderer

Is there any way to use attributes per polyline with a `MKMultiPolylineRenderer`?

Or do I have to create a different renderer even if the only difference is line width?

I tried sub-classing `MKMultiPolylineRenderer`, but I do not see anyway to tie attributes to the `CGPath` being drawn.

In the code below, `draw(mapRect:zoomScale:in:)` shows I have 1197 polylines, but `strokePath(in:)` is called only once per draw call.

If I could somehow tell what path number it was stroking I could bind attributes to the strokePath function. Since draw(mapRect:) only draws one path, I don't see how I can. If strokePath only provided an index I'd be all set.

I guess I could override the draw function entirely (and not call its super function), but I would be rendering all 1197 paths 1197 times since I don't know what path it is rendering per call.

```
class MyMultiPolylineRenderer: MKMultiPolylineRenderer {
    
    //Even though there are 1197 polylines, this is called once per draw(mapRect:)
    override func strokePath(_ path: CGPath, in context: CGContext) {
        super.strokePath(path, in: context)
        print("strokePath")
    }
    
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        
        //Causes a single call to strokePath
        super.draw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, in: context)

        var counter = 0
        for poly in self.multiPolyline.polylines {
            counter += 1
        }
        
        //polylines counter: 1197
        print("polylines counter: \(counter)")
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that MyMultiPolylineRenderer draws all polyLines with one draw call. Not 1197 draw calls. If you see multiple draw calls, that is because you get different mapRect parameters with each call when MapKit draws different portions of the mapView.

Comment: Yeah, I honestly can't make sense of what it's doing. So is there no way to know what line number is being drawn or somehow relate attributes to it?

Comment: The answer is all. Instead of printing polylines counter, print MapRect. You will notice a few calls, with different mapRects. MapKit basically divides the visible region into a few tiles, and calls draw for each tile. Each draw draws all 1197 polylines.

Comment: The standard implementation applies the renderer attributes to all polylines. With your own draw, you can ignore those attributes and use your own.

Comment: What I mean by attributes is an associated code with each polyline. Say code "100" for a creek and "500" for a trail. Then in my own draw, vary the attributes based on the code in a switch statement, so for "100" it would stroke blue and "500" it would stroke red dashes. I know how to vary the drawing, but I can't figure out how to associate a code with each polyline.

Comment: [`MKMultiPolyline`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmultipolyline) is for “when you have multiple distinct polyline shapes that you intend to render using the same style.” If you don't want them rendered in the same style, it seems the just adding a bunch of separate `MKPolyline` would be the logical approach. Changing the behavior of `MKMultiplePolylineRenderer` to behave contrary to the documentation feels like the wrong approach. Hey, sometimes we have to do what we have to do, but make sure the decision is driven by empirical results, not just a theoretical concern.

Comment: I did add a bunch of separate MKPolylines (I even state that I have 1197 of them), but I could not determine a way to associate an attribute with each line as they are drawn (also stated). It appears that @GerdCastan 's answer should work so I'm not sure what your point is. I mean, why does `MKMultiplePolylineRenderer` allow the draw function to be overridden if customized rendering is not intended?

Comment: If you mean I should just use a bunch of `MKPolylineRenderer`s instead of a `MKMultiplePolylineRenderer` it's because I would need thousands of renderers which is not feasible.

Comment: @Rob the answer works and does not do anything unusual. I feel your concern is unfounded but thanks for your interest anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need a polyline that has an opinion about its color

```
class ColoredPolyline: MKPolyline {
    var strokeColor: UIColor?
}
```

Let's create some test data:
a straight blue line from Sagrada Família to Museu Blau
and a straight yellow line from Sagrada Família to Museu Maritim:

```
func createTestColoredMultiPolyline() -> MKMultiPolyline {
    let sagradaFamília = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.4035944, longitude: 2.1743616)
    let museuBlau = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.41103109073135, longitude: 2.221040725708008)
    let museuMaritim = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.37546408659406, longitude: 2.1759045124053955)
    
    let toBlauCoordinates = [sagradaFamília, museuBlau]
    let polylineToMuseuBlau = ColoredPolyline(coordinates: toBlauCoordinates, count: toBlauCoordinates.count)
    polylineToMuseuBlau.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    
    let toMaritimCoordinates = [sagradaFamília, museuMaritim]
    let polylineToMuseuMaritim = ColoredPolyline(coordinates: toMaritimCoordinates, count: toMaritimCoordinates.count)
    polylineToMuseuMaritim.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow
    
    let testMultiPolyline = MKMultiPolyline([polylineToMuseuBlau, polylineToMuseuMaritim])
    
    return testMultiPolyline
}
```

Note that the sequence of those polylines matters, should you draw them on top of each other.

now let's write a `MKMultiPolylineRenderer` that respects the color of `ColoredPolyline` (and uses color of `MKMultiPolylineRenderer` in other cases):

```
class MultiColorMultipolylinerenderer: MKMultiPolylineRenderer {
    
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        let roadWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale)
        
        /// if polylines draw on top of each other the creator of self.multiPolyline is responsible for the correct sequence
        let polylines = self.multiPolyline.polylines
        
        context.saveGState()

        for polyline in polylines {
            // get coordinates of polyline
            let polylineMapPoints = polyline.coordinates.map { coord in
                MKMapPoint(coord)
            }
            guard polylineMapPoints.count > 0 else {
                continue
            }

            let coloredPolyline = polyline as? ColoredPolyline
            // usually all polylines in a MultiColorMultipolylinerenderer are rendered with the same self.strokeColor
            // but we let ColoredPolyline have its own opinion
            let polylineStrokeColor = coloredPolyline?.strokeColor ?? self.strokeColor ?? UIColor.label
            

            // stroke properties to context
            context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.exclusion)
            context.setStrokeColor(polylineStrokeColor.cgColor)

            if self.lineWidth > 0 {
                context.setLineWidth(self.lineWidth*roadWidth)
            } else {
                context.setLineWidth(roadWidth)
            }
            context.setLineJoin(self.lineJoin)
            context.setLineCap(self.lineCap)
            context.setMiterLimit(self.miterLimit)
            
            // create path
            context.move(to: self.point(for: polylineMapPoints[0]))
            for element in 1 ..< polyline.pointCount {
                let point_ = self.point(for: polylineMapPoints[element])
                context.addLine(to: point_)
            }
            
            // draw previously created path
            context.drawPath(using: .stroke)
            
        }
        
        context.restoreGState()

    }
    
}
```

that code uses a little helper:

```
public extension MKMultiPoint {
    var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, count: pointCount)
        getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pointCount))
        return coords
    }
}
```

This is how the test data looks in my tourist app:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't think of sub-classing `MKPolyline`. This looks like it should work! I'll try it out soon and accept your answer if it works and I suspect it will.

Comment: It works, thank you! I only wish you would have got the 200 points for when I had a bounty for this question. Note that `MKPolyLine` has `.points()` that is an array of `MKMapPoint`s so it works using that without your extension. Is there any reason I should still use the extension instead?